# Kubernetes Ingress patch

Tags: kubernetes

I want to change the host and tls hosts values on Kubernetes Ingress, but I don't know why I am getting the following error.

```
kubectl patch ing/test-ingress --type=json -p='[{"op": "replace", "host": "example.com", "value":"test.com"}]' -n test
```

The request is invalid: the server rejected our request due to an error in our request

Comment: if you got an error from the api server, it would be useful to show it. Currently you only show the kubectl command.

Comment: at first glance, I would say its because there is no top level field `host` in the ingress manifest. Host would be like `/spec/rules/0/host`.